# How to implement an editable for a TreeListEx field in sitecore/glassmapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

I have a field in sitecore that is a TreeListEx. I need to support this field in the experience editor. I'm using MVC controller renderings.

I'm having difficulty finding anything that gives me any pointers in how to do this. The [glass doc's don't mention TreeLists](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial14). I found [this tutorial](https://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/editframe-with-sitecore-mvc-and-glass-mapper/) but I can't relate some of the items it talks about to my sitecore implementation. Specifically it talks about :

> In core database, under /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit
>   Frame Buttons, add your field, making a duplicate of the
>   /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/Default
>   folder for convenience. This will bring over with it the below items.

I don't have this setup...? The path it talks about does not exist in my sitecore. I'm guessing this is an older version (I'm on sitecore 8)

I'm 90% sure I need to use a glass mapper `BeginEditFrame()`. This has an overload:

```
public GlassEditFrame BeginEditFrame(string buttons, string dataSource);
```

But there appears to be no documentation on how to use this. I'm guessing `datasource` would be my field holding the TreeListEx but `buttons` I have no idea?

Has anyone implemented a TreeListEx field in experience editor using MVC (glassmapper or standard, I don't mind)?

If this is possible how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come up with a workaround. It appears (happy to be contridicted here) that sitecore does not support the TreeListEx (despite this being a core feature) in MVC/experience editor.

My work around was to create the items as children of the item that used them (makes the sitecore set up much more clunky but...)

[image]

I can then use the begin edit frame thus:

```
@using (Html.BeginEditFrame(Model.Path))
{
    foreach (var button in Model.Children)
    {
        <!--Use children here-->
    }
}
```

**Note**: you will need to add whatever template(s) you want to add here as the insert options (item template -> _standardValues -> Configure -> Assign (insert options menu))

You will then be able to add the items though the experience manager:

[image]